# Don't I need to move a shrunk filesystem before resizing the partition?

Tags: filesystems, partition, resize2fs

I have a partition of size X GB filled by an ext4 filesystem. Now, I want to shrink this partition (and the filesystem) to only take up the *latter* X/2 GB. I'm using command-line tools and no `parted`. So, I've read ([here](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/reduce_the_size_of_an_ext2_ext3_or_ext4_filesystem.html) and [here](http://geekpeek.net/resize-filesystem-fdisk-resize2fs/) for example) that I need to `resize2fs` and then use `fdisk` to shrink the partition. However, what about moving the filesystem by X/2 GB forward in the partition? Isn't that a necessary step?

Also, assuming this is necessary - should I use `dd` for moving the data, or is something else necessary/better?

Answer (score 0):

Essential filesystem structures are addressed relatively to the start of the filesystem, which happens to be the same as the start of the block device. Since your filesystem is implicitly expected to start on the first block of the block device, it *tolerates no offset* at any time between the first block of the block device and the first block of the filesystem.

Your filesystem's end can be changed (grown and shrank) relatively to the starting point, but there's no easy way to extend beyond the first block (or to shrink a filesystem 'backwards'), as you'd introduce an *offset* between the block device and the start of file system on it. Theoretically this would of course be possible, however the current toolset and the Linux kernel is not prepared for this type of operation.

In the comment to this answer you stated that you only interested relocating your filesystem on a new partition covering only the second half of the current parititon.

Is a filesystem depends on which block device it uses? No. Relocation of the filesystem with different tools, such as `dd` is possible.

The procedure would look like this:

1. make a backup, it never hurts
2. shrink the existing filesystem down (or under) the size of the new partition
3. calculate the filesystem's current starting position on the disk (not on the partition)
4. repartition your disk
5. dd the amount of data on the disk to it's right place (since you know the old starting point, the new starting point and the lenght)
6. extend your filesystem (in case in step 2 you made it smaller)

I would like to highlight that this procedure will not work, if your shrinked-down filesystem (point 2) and it's desired new place (the new partition, in point 4) overlaps on the disk.

Consider using `LVM` to mitigate these issues like this and many others. With `LVM`, you could simply:

1. shrink your filesystem
2. shrink your logical volume (and let LVM handle all this mess)

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify - I don't need to the filesystem to be usable before the entire procedure is complete. So, I supposedly never need for it to support offsets. I just want to move the bytes in 0...X/2 G-1 to X/2 G ... X - 1. Theoretically, when I then resize the partition to only contain what were previously its last X/2 GB, the filesystem should fit perfectly. Or am I wrong?

Comment: the part with "0...X/2 G-1 to X/2 G ... X - 1"  was not really clear, sorry :(

Comment: I meant, from the first half of the partition to the second have of the partition. The "-1"s are because the indices are 0-based.

Comment: i hope it answers your question now ;)